# Expand when link is clicked and hide when clicked a second time

Tags: jquery

i have a script that is working but one way only.. I would like it to have it hide when the same link is clicked a second time.

```
$('.EndPoint').on('click', function () {
$('.EndPoint').find('div').hide();
$(this).find('div').show();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksvexr40/1/)

-- UPDATE 1 --

Trying to work in this solution http://jsfiddle.net/ksvexr40/2/ but its now hiding properly.. two issues 1) only part of it is getting hidden 2) it starting off as expanded. I am using .append() to bring in the data and have many instances of them.. some example below

```
                    var set = $('<div><a href="#" class="clicker"><h3>['+i+'] ' + endpoint1.ipAddress+ ' - ' +endpoint1.serverName+ '</h3></a></div>');
                $response0.append(set);

                if (endpoint1.serverName == null) {
                    var serverName = '<div class="hideThis"><b>Server Name:</b> n/a</div>';
                    set.append(serverName);
                    } else if (endpoint1.serverName != null) {
                        set.append('<div class="hideThis"><b>Server Name:</b> ' + endpoint1.serverName+'</div>');
                    } set.append('<div class="hideThis"><b>IP Address:</b> ' + endpoint1.ipAddress+ '<br></div>');
```

Comment: How about `toggle()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.is(":visible")` to check the visibility of an element:

```
$('.EndPoint').on('click', function () {
   if($(this).find('div').is(":visible"))
   {
       $(this).find('div').hide();
   }else{       
       $(this).find('div').show();
   }
}
```

Comment: yep this works perfectly.. i think your code is missing some curly braces though for if and else.. once updated it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).find('div').toggle();` Will do it

```
$('.hideThis').hide();
$('.clicker').on('click', function () {
    $('.hideThis').not($(this).next()).hide();
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ksvexr40/2/

Comment: your sample works fine but when i try to factor it in to my code only parts of it are getting hidden. I have updated my code in my post to show you an example.. i am using .append() to bring in the data